# Authenticated application scans across thousands of webapps with different credentials

Tags: web-application, vulnerability-scanners

Assuming a SOC in a Big Cap company which has >3000 web applications. Web App scans are performed at the moment, but they scratch the surface as scans are unauthenticated.

As

- there is no way SSO will be put on all of these apps (utopic),
- and putting the same credentials on all apps won't be done for obvious security reasons,
- or dealing with one password each, or cloning everything in containers out of production is a lifecycle nightmare

Is there any solution to handle authenticated scans on large scales?

Comment: You exclude shared authentication using either SSO or same credentials. Then you also exclude different credentials per app. The intersection of both is zero, i.e. you basically exclude any kind of authentication, even though you want authenticated scans. This does not match.

Comment: Hi, that's the problem indeed. If we include one of those 3 solutions, answer would have been easy.
Yet I bet most of big companies face the same issue. They have to choose from these 4 solutions : implement SSO anywhere, risky single credential, datastore of passwords, or forget about having authenticated credentials.
Ofc this is not manichean, we can sort it out app by app, based upon severity.

Comment: My point is that you cannot ask for a solution but excluding every possible option at the same time. So any of these authentication option need to be implemented by you. Which is the best (or if you run some mix of these) depends on your specific environment and applications.

Comment: Maybe you could possibly parametrize your scans with creds and write a custom script to launch the scan with different parameters each time based on the app?